# Correcting a gap in ListPlot

Tags: list-manipulation, plotting

This is a small sample of my data

```
data = {4., 13.7107, 8.70956, 2.39369, -1.952, 2.923}, {4.1, 
13.7263, 8.7468, 2.39592, -1.818, 2.712}, {4.2, 13.7425, 8.78553, 
2.39829, -1.591, 2.49}, {4.3, 13.7591, 8.82563, 2.40079, -1.257, 
2.251}, {4.4, 13.7762, 8.86697, 2.40342, -0.811, 1.988}, {4.5, 
13.7937, 8.90944, 2.40617, -0.244, 1.693}, {4.6, 13.8117, 8.95293, 
2.40902, 0.448, 1.345}, {4.7, 13.8302, 8.99732, 2.41199, 1.274, 
0.88}, {4.8, 13.849, 9.04256, 2.41505, 2.231, 1.61}, {4.9, 13.8682, 
9.08847, 2.4182, 3.33, 2.996}, {5., 13.8879, 9.13509, 2.42145, 
4.564, 4.333}, {5.1, 13.9079, 9.18224, 2.42478, 5.933, 5.76}, {5.2, 
13.9282, 9.22989, 2.42819, 7.434, 7.297}, {5.3, 13.9489, 9.27795, 
2.43168, 9.061, 8.949}, {5.4, 13.97, 9.32636, 2.43525, 10.816, 
10.723}, {5.5, 13.9914, 9.37507, 2.43889, 12.686, 12.607}, {5.6, 
14.0131, 9.42401, 2.4426, 14.661, 14.593}, {5.7, 14.0351, 9.47312, 
2.44638, 16.72, 16.66}, {5.8, 14.0575, 9.52236, 2.45022, 18.876, 
18.823}, {5.9, 14.0802, 9.57168, 2.45413, 21.077, 21.029}, {6., 
14.1031, 9.62103, 2.45811, 23.335, 23.292}}
```

Then I split them into two sublists

```
datas = {};
datau = {};
Do[
 s = data[[i, 5]];
 If[s >= -2 && s <= 2, AppendTo[datas, {data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]]}], 
 AppendTo[datau, {data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]]}]], {i, 1, Length[data]}
]
```

And finally I plot them

```
L0 = ListPlot[{datas, datau}, 
PlotStyle -> {{Darker[Green], Thick}, {Red, Thick}}, Joined -> True,
Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"a", Subscript["x", "0"]}, RotateLabel -> False, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {13.4, 15.5}}, ImageSize -> 550]
```

[image]

We see that about `a = 4.8` there is a small gap between the green and the red line. Any suggestion on how to eliminate this gap?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code does not produces same plot.

Second, you can get the data you want like this:

`datas = Cases[data, {x_, y_, _, _, z_ /; -2 <= z <= 2, __} :> {x, y}];`

`datau = Cases[data, {x_, y_, _, _, z_ /; Not[-2 <= z <= 2], __} :> {x, y}];`

Third, you need to add the end point of datas to datau

```
datau1 = Prepend[datau, datas[[-1]]];
```

or the opposite

```
datas1 = Append[datas, datau[[1]]];
```

and then plot using  `{datas1,datau}` or using `{datas,datau1}`

Comment: Thanks! It works fine. I provided here a small sample of my data and that's why my code (not cold!!!) does not produce the same plot.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `datas` and `datau` from `data` using `SplitBy`:

```
{datas, datau} = #[[All, {1, 2}]] & /@ SplitBy[data, -2 <= #[[5]] <= 2 &]
```

You can use `Mesh` and `MeshShading` to plot a single line with two colors with no gap:

```
ListLinePlot[data[[All, {1, 2}]], 
 Mesh -> {{(datas[[-1, 1]] + datau[[1, 1]])/2}}, MeshStyle -> None, 
 MeshShading -> {Directive[Thick, Green], Directive[Thick, Red]}]
```

[image]